# AutoHotKey strange issue with Copy (Ctrl-C) every other execution

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to writing my own AutoHotKey scripts so this just has to be something stupid I'm missing here.

The intent of the script is for the user to select some text and press the hot-key (<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>).  The menu pops-up and they click the menu item.  The selected text should then be copied to the clipboard.  That's all i'm trying to do right now.

The problem is that it works the first time, then fails, then works, then fails, etc.  It basically only works every other time.

I'm running Win7 x64 with the latest `AutoHotKey_l` (unicode 32bit).

I have a timeout on the `ClipWait`, and it basically just waits, never receives the copied text, and issues an ErrorLevel 1.

Here's the code:

```
#SingleInstance force
; EXAMPLE #2: This is a working script that creates a popup menu that is displayed when the user presses the Win-w hotkey.

; Create the popup menu by adding some items to it.
Menu, MyMenu, Add, Demo, Demo

return  ; End of script's auto-execute section.

Demo:
clipboard =  ; Start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived.
Send ^c
ClipWait, 2  ; Wait for the clipboard to contain text.
if ErrorLevel = 1
{
    MsgBox Copy failed
}
else
{
    MsgBox Copy worked
}
return

#w::Menu, MyMenu, Show  ; i.e. press the Win-w hotkey to show the menu.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing. Using your script exactly as-is on Win7 x64, I see "Copy worked" every time. AHK version 1.0.48.05.

Comment: Have you tried this in different programs? I'm wondering if you are using it someplace where you are losing focus on the text area or something.

Comment: Well, I knew it was something stupid.  :)   You are correct.  I was always testing in Notepad++ and that's where the problem lies.  Perhaps I have a plugin or something that is causing an issue - because I tried it in a few other text editors (UltraEdit, WordPad, etc) - and it works flawlessly in all of them.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you're making progress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have a script that behaves sporadically, and/or differently in other programs,
the first thing to try is simulating a key-press duration and/or delay period between keys.
This is because some programs aren't designed to handle the speed that AutoHotkey sends
artificial keystrokes.

Here is the most basic example:

```
f1::
Send, {ctrl down}
Sleep, 40
Send, {c down}
Sleep, 40
Send, {c up}
Sleep, 40
Send, {ctrl up}
Return
```

We have several ways to make it more concise.
The easiest (yet not always desirable since it blocks during delays, unlike sleep)
is the [`SetKeyDelay`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) command, which only works for  the SendEvent and SendPlay modes.

```
f2::
SetKeyDelay, 40 ; could be set at the top of the script instead.
Send, {ctrl down}{c down}{c up}{ctrl up}
Return
```

Those using AHK_L can make use of a for-loop and an array:

```
f3::
For i, element in array := ["{ctrl down}","{c down}","{c up}","{ctrl up}"] {
   Sendinput, %element%
   Sleep, 40
} Return
```

And those using AHK basic (or AHK_L) can use `Loop, Parse`:

```
f4::
list := "{ctrl down},{c down},{c up},{ctrl up}"
Loop Parse, list, `,
{
    Sendinput, %A_LoopField%
    Sleep, 40
} Return
```

It's useful to read about the three [Sendmodes](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SendMode.htm).
More information can be found at the bottom of the [Send command's page](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm).