# How to remap key in certain case and not remap in other case with autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap <kbd>alt+e</kbd> when caps is on in autocad.

And when <kbd>capslock</kbd> is not on, <kbd>alt+e</kbd> should open menu edit.

I use script like this

```
<!e::
if(GetKeyState( "CAPSLOCK", "T" ))
{
    SendInput erase{space}wp{space}
}
else
{
    Send !e
}
```

When I turn on <kbd>capslock</kbd>, remap key is OK.

When I turn off <kbd>capslock</kbd>and <kbd>alt+e</kbd>, menu edit opened, but closed immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to post question at [autohotkey community](http://www.autohotkey.com/community). But it always give me error: You have provided an invalid answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want a `$` at the beginning of your hotkey to prevent the endless loop that the `!e` in your else block will trigger. You will also want to add a `Return` at the end of the hotkey to prevent the script from continuing into what is below this hotkey.

```
$!e::
if GetKeyState( "CapsLock", "T" )
    Sendinput, erase{space}wp{space}
else
    Sendinput, !e
Return
```

(Brackets are only required when if/else blocks are more than one line.)

Beyond that, the likely issue is that it's an alt hotkey that is also set to send alt.
I say this is an issue because if you press and hold alt, it activates menus,
and then the script sends alt, which will be in conflict with that.
As Ricardo said, the ideal way to script this is with the `#IF` command (only included with AHK_L).

```
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") and WinActive("AutoCAD")

!e:: SendInput, erase{space}wp{space}

#If
```

Notice that you can add the [WinActive()](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/Functions.htm#WinActive) function to the `#If` command's expression.
Try it without that first, and also realize that the application's title needs to be exactly "AutoCAD" at all times for that to work. I would recommend finding AutoCad's ahk_class,
with AHK's window spy, instead of using the title.

If it still does not work, it is likely that AHK is sending faster than AutoCAD would like to receive.
Info on how to deal with that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130800/1217270).

Comment: Thanks Honest. Now I use shift+e instead of alt+e. I try your script and autohotkey_L. When caps is turn on, alt+e is not open menu edit, but input string "{ctrl}e" in autocad.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your else block to this:

```
Send, {ALTDOWN}e{ALTUP}
```

I do not rely on these symbols to send keystrokes in AutoHotKey.

Comment: `#If GetKeyState( "CAPSLOCK", "T" )
<!e::
Send, erase{SPACE}wp{SPACE}
return`

Comment: When I lanch "#If GetKeyState( "CAPSLOCK", "T" ) <!e:: Send, erase{SPACE}wp{SPACE} return". It error: Invalid hotkey

Comment: I could not break lines in my last comment. The small code contains **four** lines, the _first_ is `#If GetKeyState ( "CAPSLOCK", "T" )`, the _second_ is `<!e::`, the _third_ is `Send, erase{SPACE}wp{SPACE}` and the _fourth_ and last is `return`.

Comment: Thanks. But I got error: LineText: #If....This line does not contain a recognized action. And I changed #If to If, this error is disappears. But another error Appeard to line erase....

Comment: Thanks. I updated to Autohotkey_l. The up code can be loaded. But keybounding ctrl+e can not switch by caps. And "#IfWinActive AutoCAD" did not work in autohotkey_l.

Comment: Sorry, I just tested the hotkey Alt+e in a notepad window, I can't help you in the AutoCAD application. The code provided worked smoothly here.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I use shift+e instead of alt+e. It works fine now.